How to Fetch All Group Calendars in My Tenant Using Delegated Permissions?
I'm currently working on fetching the list of groups using app-only permissions and accessing group calendars using delegated permissions. However, I am facing limitations where I can only fetch public groups and some private groups where the delegated account is a member or owner. My goal is to fetch all group calendars within my tenant.
Here is my setup:
I am using app-only permissions to fetch the list of groups.
I am using delegated permissions to access group calendars.
I am a global administrator and using my account for delegated permissions.
Issues:
I can only access public groups and some private groups where my account is a member or owner.
I need to fetch all group calendars across my tenant, regardless of my membership status in those groups.
Is there any way to fetch all the group calendars in my tenant using delegated permissions or any other method?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

When you are making use of delegated flow you are signing in as user and so only user group calender events can be fetched

AFAIK it is not possible to fetch Fetch All Group Calendars in Tenant Using Delegated Permissions

Note that: By using delegated API permissions, you can only access signed-in user Group Calendar not all group calendars present in the tenant.
Yes. you are right, you can only fetch the calendar groups where you are the member or owner of it. And hence it is not possible to fetch all the Group calendars of your tenant.
As a workaround, you can try granting Calendars.Read application permission and access any users group calendar of your tenant as application by passing the User ID like below:


Application permissions are tenant wide and gives access to the application globally.

Generated access token by passing parameters like below:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope↵:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


By using the above access token, you can access all users Group Calendar as application:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/calendarGroups


Reference:
List calendarGroups - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
